# Detecting changes in a bound list of entities using data repositories

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a c# winforms application using a bindingsource and a data grid.

I am using a repository pattern from Julie Lerman to set up data to bind to a grid.

THe patern relies on entities implementing an IEntity interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    EntityState State { get; set; }
}
```

When I edit a record and try to save, my changes don't get saved, this is because changes to the bound entities do not set the IEntity.State property.

What should I be doing to cause the State property to be set?

The code to set the bindingSource is

```
 using (var repo = new PeopleRepository(new OrganisationContext()))
        {
                IList<Person> lst = repo.GetList(p => p.Id > 0 && p.Archived == false, x => x.Organisation);
                bindingSource.datasource = (List<Person>)lst;
        }
```

The repository code contains

```
 public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        List<T> list;
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = ((DbContext)this.context).Set<T>();

        //Apply eager loading
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);
        }

         list = dbQuery.AsNoTracking().Where(where).ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

When saving I call the following, but it doesn't work because the state flags are not set.

```
    public void Save(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {


        if (entities.Count(p => ((IEntity)p).State == EntityState.Added) > 0)
        {
            this.Add(entities.Where(p => ((IEntity)p).State == EntityState.Added).ToArray());
        }

        if (entities.Count(p => ((IEntity)p).State == EntityState.Modified) > 0)
        {
            this.Update(entities.Where(p => ((IEntity)p).State == EntityState.Modified).ToArray());
        }

        if (entities.Count(p => ((IEntity)p).State == EntityState.Deleted) > 0)
        {
            this.Remove(entities.Where(p => ((IEntity)p).State == EntityState.Deleted).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

[update]
I am using the binding navigator for add and delete buttons

Comment: Does the UI modify the `EntityState State { get; set; }` property and bring it to the repository?

Comment: it doesn't, that is what I want to figure out how to do.

Comment: then you need to manage the state on the UI before the entities are saved, something like `on add button click { State = Added; }`, `on edit cell changed { State = Modified; }`, `on remove button click { State = Deleted; Visible = false; }`

Comment: on the right track.. .still trying to figure out which events

Comment: I'm not sure what are you using in the UI and how you feed and save the data, you need to provide more information about the UI